# Enum translation in Spring Data REST repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.4, Spring Data REST, HATEOAS. I'm exposing REST endpoints to be consumed from a Angular client.

I'm using `spring.data.rest.enable-enum-translation=true` to convert enums. It works fine both in `GET` and `POST` requests exposed from Spring Data REST from repositories.

I added a custom method in a repository:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public interface TransitCertificateRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<TransitCertificate, Long> {   

    @Query("SELECT t FROM TransitCertificate t WHERE :states IS NULL OR status IN (:states) ")
    public Page<TransitCertificate> findAllByParameters(
            @Param("states") @RequestParam(value = "states", required = false) List<TransitCertificateStatus> states, Pageable pageable);
```

This is the enum:

```
    public enum TransitCertificateStatus {
         PENDING, USED, CANCELED, ARCHIVED
    }
```

This is the relevant part of the model:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(TransitCertificateListener.class)
public class TransitCertificate extends AbstractEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5978999252424024545L;

    @NotNull(message = "The status cannot be empty")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TransitCertificateStatus status = TransitCertificateStatus.PENDING;
```

In `rest-messages.properties` I've translation for the enum like:

```
server.model.enums.TransitCertificateStatus.PENDING = Pending
server.model.enums.TransitCertificateStatus.USED = Used
```

When the client try to call my method `findAllByParameters` and sends a array of String (translated how the server sent back), the conversion on the server fails.
I don't understand why the conversion works in save() method, for example, but not in my method.
Furthemore if the client sends me 2 states, Spring returns this error:

```
Parameter value element [USED] did not match expected type [server.model.enums.TransitCertificateStatus (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [USED] did not match expected type [server.model.enums.TransitCertificateStatus (n/a)]
```

So I guess I've two problems:

1. For some reason Spring is not able to convert a `String[]` to a `List<TransitCertificateStatus>` even if the value is exactly the one defined in the TransitCertificateStatus (PENDING, USED, CANCELED, ARCHIVED)
2. Spring is not able to convert the String the client send, to the right enum when the value is one of that defined in `rest-messages.properties` (Pending, Used, etc).

Is there a way to solve the problem is a elegant way using internal facilities of Spring Data REST (I point out enum transation works in save() method) without reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Makes me think of [@Annotatiomania™](http://www.annotatiomania.com/) ;)

Comment: Are you sending "USED" from client? The rest-message.properties mapping has "Used".

Comment: @RaiyanMohammed I tried in both ways. Anyway I expect it works in both ways like in save() methods.

Comment: @sp00m advice are appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up to solve the problem in this way:

- I created a custom @RepositoryRestController
- I created my method
- I get the enum from the client like a String and then I convert it. In this way the client can send also the translated string for the enum

This a piece of code:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/licensePlates/searches")
    public ResponseEntity<?> search(@RequestBody(required = true) List<Filter> filters, Pageable pageable, Locale locale,
            PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler) {
EngineType engineType = enumTranslator.fromText(EngineType.class, filterMap.get("engineType"));
```

You have to inject enumTranslation in this way:

```
@Autowired
private EnumTranslator enumTranslator;
```

Not sure is the best way but that solved my problem with little code.